# Sleep and Charge USB ports on laptops/netbooks: Do other manufacturers besides Toshiba have them?

Tags: laptop, usb, netbook, power

The sleep-and-charge USB port feature of Toshiba laptops is interesting. One can use the relatively big laptop battery to charge cellphones, mp3 players etc.

I have seen this feature mentioned for Toshiba laptops. I was wondering if another manufacturer provides the same feature, possibly using a different name.

Comment: My Acer 5735 laptop also powers the USB ports while in sleep mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dell Latitude E series has this feature. They call it Powershare

Comment: I had occasion to use my brother's Acer Aspire One netbook (the one with an 8G solid state drive) and noticed that it powered its USB ports when in sleep mode. So I imagine that this feature is somewhat common. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

most ASUS Eee PCs have power on the USB ports even when turned off.

although the nice folks at shlashgear call this feature a ["a true stroke of innovative genius"](http://www.slashgear.com/toshiba-sleep-and-charge-usb-ports-a-true-stroke-of-innovative-genius-0211025/), many users i know consider it a pain in the behind as it drains the battery when you 'forget' to unplug a device that is drawing power. :)

Comment: I have to agree with you there. One man's feature is another man's bug.

Answer (score 0):

Apple laptops do this as well.